# Question about + and the is operator in groovy

Tags: groovy

Why is this OK:

```
assert 'foo'+' bar'.is('foo baz')
```

?

This fails, but that is OK:

```
assert 'foo'+' bar' == 'foo baz'
```

Comment: `'foo'+' bar'.is('foo baz')` evaluated to `°foofalse'` that is a groovy truth.

Comment: `assert 'foo' + ' bar'.is('foo baz') == 'foofalse'` 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
assert 'foo'+'bar'.is('foo baz')
```

`.` evaluated before `+`

so this expression is the same as

```
assert 'foo'+ ('bar'.is('foo baz'))
assert 'foo'+ false
assert 'foofalse'
```

Answer (score 0):

Equality and identity are 2 different notions.  `is` tests identiy which is to say it tests if 2 references point to the same object.  `==` tests equality which is to say it tests whether the objects are "equal" to each other and equality is defined by the `equals` method (or sometimes the `compareTo` method in some circumstances).